# Jmeter showing error : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'shubham@localhost'@'118.185.61.226' (using password: YES))

Tags: mysql, jmeter

When i have created a JDBC request sampler in jmeter and used jmeter connection configuration element and when i try to create a connection with DB  following error is showing again and again can anyone please give me resolution for this?

Error : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'shubham@localhost'@'115.248.185.130' (using password: YES))

I am also attaching the screenshot of the error :

[image: THis is the error showing]

Configuration element screen shot :

[image: THis is the JDBC configuration element screenshot where ipofDB is my db ip]

Can anyone please help me resolving this issue ?

Comment: can you show your JDBC configuration?

Comment: already share the screenshot with text "https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDKxP.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more about MySQL configuration rather than JMeter. The error you're getting means that `shubham` user is not allowed to connect from `115.248.185.130` host.

So:

1. First of all you have incorrect JDBC URL, looking into [Connection URL Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html) it should be in form of:

   ```
   protocol//[hosts][/database][?properties]
   ```

   most probably you need to remove `phpmyadmin` from your URL
2. Execute the following query on MySQL server side:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON ipofDB.* TO shubham@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ```

   This will allow access not only from localhost and `115.248.185.130`, but also from **any** other host just in case you will go for [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

References:

- [MySQL: Adding User Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html)
- [MySQL Database and JMeter - How to Test Your Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection)