# In Jmeter Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: java, jmeter

[image][image]I am trying to run select query in jmeter. I am getting this response in listners "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory" I have attached my myphpadmin page which I use to create db. Thanks in advance.

[image].png

[image]

Comment: Check my answer below, if ok you should accept it and upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[JDBC jar](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) should be in **lib** folder:

> Fully qualified name of driver class. (Must be in JMeter's classpath - easiest to copy .jar file into JMeter's /lib directory).

I assume you use your jar for `MySQL` DB:

> The list of the validation queries can be configured with jdbc.config.jdbc.driver.class property and are by default:
>
> MySQL
> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Did it. Any suggestion for this one please : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Comment: @Durairajs see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114832/jmeter-showing-error-cannot-create-poolableconnectionfactory-access-denied-fo

Comment: @Durairajs in addition set `Max Number of connections` 1 in JDBC Configuration

Comment: @Durairajs set configuration of `Validation Query` to `select 1`

Comment: I have everything you have asked me to. I have attached my myphpadmin  also. please check my Database URL for the same

Comment: @Durairajs see MySQL solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to put the .jar into the "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or other folder which is in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. You need to **restart** JMeter to pick the .jar

Check out [MySQL Database and JMeter - How to Test Your Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection) for more information

Comment: Thanks did it. Now I have this response : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Comment: You have a typo in JDBC url, remove space from it (before the database name)

Answer (score 1):

On JMeter side check:

- driver of MySQL (correct version) is in lib folder. The Jar not a zip.
- The URL format is correct based on [this document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html), **there seems to be a space before database name in your URL**
- Login / password are also correct, check for strange characters or bad copy/paste

If all those are ok, then you're most probably facing same issues as the ones described here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2985169/460802